# rewrite doubly linked list to stl container

Tags: c++, c, stl

I use **doubly linked list** to store users.
As you can see deleting user from any position in list is quite easy. I only provide a pointer to user struct to Removefromlist function.

```
typedef struct _user {
     ...
    struct _user  *pCtxtBack; 
    struct _user *pCtxtForward;
   } user, *PPER_user;  

PPER_user UserList;  // head of list

VOID Removefromlist(PPER_user lpUser) { //pointer to allocated user

    PPER_user pBack;
    PPER_user pForward;

    pBack       = lpUser->pCtxtBack;
    pForward    = lpUser->pCtxtForward;

    if( ( pBack == NULL ) && ( pForward == NULL ) ) {

        // This is the only node in the list to delete
          UsersList = NULL;
    } else if ( ( pBack == NULL ) && ( pForward != NULL ) ) {

        // This is the start node in the list to delete
        pForward->pCtxtBack = NULL;
    } else if ( ( pBack != NULL ) && ( pForward == NULL ) ) {

        // This is the end node in the list to delete
        pBack->pCtxtForward = NULL;
                    UsersList = pBack;
    } else if( pBack && pForward ) {

       // Neither start node nor end node in the list
        pBack->pCtxtForward = pForward;
        pForward->pCtxtBack = pBack;
    }

    free(lpUser);

}
```

Now I'm trying to rewrite my list in more c++ style and use some stl containers(I know a very little about them). Which one should I choose to keep Removefromlist function functionality? for example: I allocate a hundred users with **new**, add them to container, then I should be able to remove any of user supplying only pointer to user structure to  container.

Comment: Just replace your list with `std::list`.

Comment: ... [`std::list<user>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and strip out the Ctx pointers. you won't need them anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::list` template implements a doubly linked list.

Suggested changes:

```
typedef struct _user {
     ...
    // Not needed: struct _user  *pCtxtBack; 
    // Not needed: struct _user *pCtxtForward;
   } user;  

std::list<user> UserList;  // The container. To get the head of the list
                           // use auto head = std::begin(UserList); 

void Removefromlist(std::list<user>::const_iterator user) { //iterator to user in list

UserList.erase(user);
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/ or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list for mor information on std::list